# Fluent Api Include Where Clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I need to get products with cover picture. But when i add `pic => pic.IsCover` it's throw exception.Otherwise there is no problem. How can i fixed it?

Error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Parametre adı: path

Thanks to all

```
_db.ProdSmartSorts
    .Where(x => catIds.Contains((int)x.Product.CategoryId))
    .OrderBy(x => x.ProdSmartId)
    .Select(x => x.Product)
    .Include(p => p.Pictures.Where(pic => pic.IsCover))
    .Skip(prodCount * (pageNumber - 1))
    .Take(prodCount)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Try to use SelectMany instead of Select

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework does not support filtering with the `Include` method.  You can vote for it here, though: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47

Answer (score 0):

Does placing the .Include() method call directly after the DbSet work?  i.e.

```
_db.ProdSmartSorts
 .Include(p => p.Pictures)
 .Where(x => catIds.Contains((int)x.Product.CategoryId))
 .OrderBy(x => x.ProdSmartId)
 .Select(x => x.Product)
 .Skip(prodCount * (pageNumber - 1))
 .Take(prodCount)
 .ToList();
```

I think the Include method is only available on the DbSet objects within the dbContext.  If you try and put it further down the chain you only have methods that are available to IQueryable or IEnumerable objects dependant on the circumstances.

Also, to my knowledge you can't use the Include function to filter, as you attempted.  So you will have to load all images related Picture entities.

**EDIT**: Sorry - just realised that this question is specifically asking for filtering on the Include() method. Please disregard.